# Issues with the tooltip position when the element is near the edge

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I recently upgraded to Bootstrap 5.1 and now have the problem that the tooltips are no longer positioned as they were in 4.6.

What can I do? I already tried with `data-bs-placement` but that is ignored on the element near the edge.

Bootstrap 4.6 ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n0g4kj9r/)):

[image: 4.6]

Bootstrap 5.1 ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p5q14jgw/2/)):

[image: 5.1]

Comment: You haven't told us what you're trying to accomplish. "As they were" doesn't cut it.

Comment: Both libraries ignore explicit placement if it doesn't work. It's probably just that the fallback algorithm varies a bit.

Comment: you can inform your query/issue in official here - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues

Comment: @isherwood Primarily that it looks visually prettier, that means that the arrow is better positioned. If the tooltip can also be placed on top, like in 4.6, that would be great.

Comment: @HDP i found an issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35340 
So at the moment I can not do anything (?)